# What is the way to separate command line output (processing from user interaction) on Unix?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, command-line, pipe

I'm writing a console application in which user interaction might be necessary (prompt for keyboard input, cli arguments etc.), but I want to keep it separate from the result of the processing (which goes to cout, in a way that it can be piped to some other application).

How can I achieve this, if I can't just send all interaction with the user to cerr (not everything is an error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your stdout is piped somewhere else, the only way to show something on the terminal (apart from maybe things like curses and dialog) is stderr.

Comment: This is what I've ended up doing and for the scope of the task it was adequate. Thank you! (Also, chosen this as best answer because it was the clearest.)

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/tty` is the usual way, but it's also possible on most Unix-like operating systems to read from `cerr`/`stderr` because the system usually opens the tty once as `stdin` and `dup()`s it onto `stdout` and `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need user interaction, open /dev/tty, it will be the controlling terminal for the process.  Standard error and standard input may be redirected as well.